# Java inheritance hierarchy -- implementing an interface a super-class is implementing

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

When I extend a class, say class A in class B, i'm implementing all interfaces that class A implements.

In the following,

```
interface INTF { ... }

class A implements INTF { ... }

class B extends A { .... }
```

class B, being a descendant of class A, is implementing INTF.

So, what's my gain in declaring class B as

```
class B extends A implements INTF { .... }
```

?

//===========================

EDIT:

Java APIs are doing this. Eg.:

```
public class LinkedHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> { ...
```

what for ?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference if your sub class restates that it implements an interface.But there is a huge gain when it comes to Reflection API.I have personally faced it..

When you call `B.class.getInterfaces()` ,it returns a Class[] containing only those interfaces explicitly declared by the class and not its superclasses,although in reality it is  implementing interfaces which are implemented by its superclasses.
  To solve it,you need to recursively call the super class and get all the interfaces implemented.Declaring an interface explicitly in your sub class will help you in this case

Comment: Apache Commons-Lang provides a nice helper method [ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces(java.lang.Class)).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to re-declare the interface again. However, there will be differences if you using Java reflections - **B.class.getInterfaces()**.

- If you don't re-declare the interface again. **B.class.getInterfaces() -- return zero interface**
- If you re-declare the interface **B.class.getInterfaces() - Return one interface**

So deciding to re-declare the interface again or Not depending on how you use java reflections on it. For most case, we don't re-declare it again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify the interface again.  You could specify all the implemented methods again, but you don't have to do that either.

If `A` changes the interface it implements in future B might not need to know about it.

Comment: @user3880721 no particualrly good reason.  Someone added it once and they don't remove something once it is added for fear of breaking backward compatibility

Comment: was it ever relevant in earlier versions? if A is implementing INTF it is implementing it all-- any descendant of A is overriding what A has. has Java been any otherwise?

Comment: @user3880721 no, but best practices change over time.  When it was added, the author might not have thought it was better to not be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference whether you specify that B implements INTF or not, since it must implement it anyway, since A is implementing it.

I'm not sure why Java APIs are doing it. I'm assuming they simply want to make it more clear to the user of `LinkedHashMap` that it implements `Map` (otherwise the user would have to look at the declaration of `HashMap` to find this out).